# What does it mean to be "être pour le nucléaire?"

Tags: grammaire, sens

For example if one says:

"Jean est pour le nucléaire".

What does it mean? I did guess that it means to the person be a family one, someone really close to the family. Am I wrong?

Comment: In [this debate](http://www.conserve-energy-future.com/pros-and-cons-of-nuclear-energy.php) (pros and cons of nuclear energy), it means Jean thinks the pros outweight the cons and nuclear energy should be pursued.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It surely means that this person "Jean" is for the nuclear energy (implicitly said).

It's a shorcut to "Jean est favorable à l'énergie nucléaire".